# Basic Interrupt Operation in C

Tags: c, microcontroller, mplab

I have this Interrupt service routine that has an operation in it, and I am not quite sure how it works. I'm sort of a beginner in C so anyone's help would be appreciated.

In the ISR subroutine, I am not exactly sure how "count++" works. It is compared to "RESTART_COUNT" and now I'm thinking that two things are happening in one line of code: That "count" is being incremented once and that RESTART_COUNT is being compared to after that increment. ***"RESTART_COUNT" is defined as being equal to 10 in a macro at the very beginning of the code.***

```
void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _T3Interrupt(void)
{

int count;

    IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;          // clear Tmr3 interrupt flag

    StopMotor();
    IEC0bits.ADIE = 0;          // disable ADC interrupt
    IEC0bits.CNIE = 0;          // disable CN interrupt
    IEC0bits.T3IE = 0;          // disable Tmr3 interrupt

    T3CONbits.TON = 1;          // restart tmr3
    count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (IFS0bits.T3IF)      //interrupt flag on?
        {
            IFS0bits.T3IF = 0;  // clear flag
            if (count++ >= RESTART_COUNT) 
            {
                IEC0bits.ADIE = 1;  // enable ADC interrupt
                IEC0bits.CNIE = 1;  // enable CN interrupt
                T3CONbits.TON = 0;  // stop tmr3
                IEC0bits.T3IE = 1;  // enable Tmr3 interrupt
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: It seems the loop waits until the timer interrupt 3 has occurred 10 times before it enables the ADC interrupt again

Comment: My guess is he knows that 10 interrupts will fire in the time between when he enables ADC and when an operation of interest completes, and then he wants to enable a TMR3 interrupt to allow whatever hardware acquisition process is happening to get to the next state.

Comment: I am really wondering how one can write SUCH ISR!!!

Answer (score 1):

The increment takes place after the comparison for `count ++`, other way around for `++ count`.

Also, I think usually it makes much more sense with `count ++ <= RESTART_COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

`count ++` is a post-increment, so the first thing tha will happen is the comparison.
`++ count` is a pre-increment, so then the increment will happen before the comparison